# Error while deploying cas-overlay 4.2.4 on weblogic 12c server

Tags: cas, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy the cas-overlay 4.2.4 on weblogic 12c server and got the below error.

Any idea ?

**Error logs**

```
weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -noexit -adminurl t3://localhost:7001 -user weblogic -redeploy -name cas-4.2.4 -source C:\Project_Gitlab\cas-overlay-template\target/cas.war -targets AdminServer -upload
<17-Aug-2016 10:05:09 o'clock BST> <Info> <J2EE Deployment SPI> <BEA-260121> <Initiating redeploy operation for application, cas-4.2.4 [archive: C:\Project_Gitlab\cas-overlay-template\target\cas.war], to AdminServer .> 
Task 2 initiated: [Deployer:149026]deploy application cas-4.2.4 on AdminServer.
Task 2 failed: [Deployer:149026]deploy application cas-4.2.4 on AdminServer.
Target state: redeploy failed on Server AdminServer

weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
  <231:11> problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected element 'tracking-mode@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee' instead of 'cookie-config@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee' here in element session-config@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
```

**Update:-**

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <display-name>Central Authentication System (CAS)</display-name>
.......

<session-config>
    <!-- Default to 5 minute session timeouts -->
    <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Comment: have you find a solution